# Google Place Api not return Anything with volley

Tags: java, android, git, google-maps, android-volley

I am trying to get back some values from Google place api  but for unknown reason it doesn't return anything, not even an error message. I am currently using volley library to consume the api.  I have tested the api call with git hub api and it works.I plan to use the return value to display markers on the map.

```
package catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import database.DatabaseHandler;
import database.Marker;
import utility.GooglePlace;
import utility.Helper;
import utility.MapUtilities;

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    JSONObject places;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        try {
            initilizeMap();
            MapUtilities.setMapSetting(googleMap);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            java.util.List<Marker> markers = db.getAllMarker();
            GooglePlace place = new GooglePlace();
            places = place.getValue(getApplicationContext());


            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

            JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                    (Request.Method.GET,"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.88471,151.218237&radius=100&sensor=true&key=Key", places,
                            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                   System.out.println(response + "");
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            System.out.println(error);

                        }
                    });
             queue.add(jsObjRequest);

            for(Marker x : markers){
                googleMap.addMarker(getMarkerOptions(x));
            }

            for(Marker x : markers)
            {
                if(intent.getStringExtra("name").equals(x.getName()))
                {
                    MapUtilities.setCameraPosition(x, 9, googleMap);
                    break;
                }
                MapUtilities.setCameraPosition(x, 9, googleMap);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private MarkerOptions getMarkerOptions(Marker x) {
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(
                           x.getLatitude(),
                           x.getLongitude()))
                           .title(x.getName() + " \n" + " \n" + x.getType());

        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(Helper.setIconColor(x)));
        return marker;
    }


    public void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_map, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     */

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

LogCat

```
04-09 00:04:53.519  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-09 00:04:54.464  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ onDetachedFromWindow
04-09 00:04:54.464  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-09 00:04:54.519  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-09 00:04:54.614  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-09 00:04:56.724  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-09 00:04:56.734  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary E/dalvikvm﹕ dvmPauseGc(AppLaunch) called - cookie=0x2f09 (f=0x1)
04-09 00:04:56.739  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
04-09 00:04:56.774  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
04-09 00:04:56.894  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/zzx﹕ Making Creator dynamically
04-09 00:04:56.934  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services client version: 7095000
04-09 00:04:56.949  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 7099038
04-09 00:05:03.969  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:168 height:63 bitmap id is 234
04-09 00:05:04.144  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:66 height:66 bitmap id is 235
04-09 00:05:04.154  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:66 height:66 bitmap id is 236
04-09 00:05:04.174  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:126 height:126 bitmap id is 237
04-09 00:05:04.179  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:126 height:126 bitmap id is 238
04-09 00:05:04.229  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-09 00:05:04.234  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:84 height:84 bitmap id is 239
04-09 00:05:04.239  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 8
04-09 00:05:04.239  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-09 00:05:04.244  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 8
04-09 00:05:04.244  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-09 00:05:04.259  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:126 height:120 bitmap id is 240
04-09 00:05:04.264  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:126 height:120 bitmap id is 241
04-09 00:05:04.269  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:126 height:120 bitmap id is 242
04-09 00:05:04.289  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:126 height:120 bitmap id is 243
04-09 00:05:04.294  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:126 height:120 bitmap id is 244
04-09 00:05:04.299  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:126 height:120 bitmap id is 245
04-09 00:05:04.324  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:120 height:120 bitmap id is 246
04-09 00:05:04.334  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:120 height:120 bitmap id is 247
04-09 00:05:04.339  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:120 height:120 bitmap id is 248
04-09 00:05:04.834  30238-31002/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary W/ActivityThread﹕ ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
04-09 00:05:05.049  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:92 height:99 bitmap id is 249
04-09 00:05:05.269  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-09 00:05:05.269  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-09 00:05:05.674  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:68 height:123 bitmap id is 250
04-09 00:05:07.289  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:68 height:123 bitmap id is 251
04-09 00:05:07.564  30238-31020/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/System.out﹕ Thread-3992(HTTPLog):isShipBuild true
04-09 00:05:07.574  30238-31020/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/System.out﹕ Thread-3992(HTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
04-09 00:05:07.574  30238-31002/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/System.out﹕ Thread-3985(HTTPLog):isShipBuild true
04-09 00:05:07.579  30238-31002/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/System.out﹕ Thread-3985(HTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
04-09 00:05:07.614  30238-31025/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/System.out﹕ Thread-3997(HTTPLog):isShipBuild true
04-09 00:05:07.619  30238-31025/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/System.out﹕ Thread-3997(HTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
04-09 00:05:07.879  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:68 height:123 bitmap id is 252
04-09 00:05:08.204  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-09 00:05:08.204  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-09 00:05:08.214  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-09 00:05:08.214  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-09 00:05:08.219  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 688 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-09 00:05:08.239  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-09 00:05:08.684  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
04-09 00:05:08.684  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/Ads﹕ Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("4E6F9C986FD085E46324EE7758AEE22E") to get test ads on this device.
04-09 00:05:08.719  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-09 00:05:08.949  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary E/ion﹕ ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
04-09 00:05:08.949  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:16 height:256 bitmap id is 253
04-09 00:05:08.954  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:128 height:256 bitmap id is 254
04-09 00:05:08.969  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:128 height:256 bitmap id is 255
04-09 00:05:09.004  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:128 height:256 bitmap id is 256
04-09 00:05:09.004  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-09 00:05:09.004  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-09 00:05:09.019  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:128 height:256 bitmap id is 257
04-09 00:05:09.044  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:128 height:256 bitmap id is 258
04-09 00:05:09.064  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:16 height:256 bitmap id is 259
04-09 00:05:09.074  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:128 height:256 bitmap id is 260
04-09 00:05:09.089  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:128 height:256 bitmap id is 261
04-09 00:05:09.094  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:128 height:256 bitmap id is 262
04-09 00:05:09.119  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:128 height:256 bitmap id is 263
04-09 00:05:09.139  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:64 height:128 bitmap id is 264
04-09 00:05:09.144  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:64 height:128 bitmap id is 265
04-09 00:05:09.149  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:64 height:128 bitmap id is 266
04-09 00:05:09.159  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary E/dalvikvm﹕ dvmResumeGc(0x2f09, 0) called (f=0x1)
04-09 00:05:09.164  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:32 height:64 bitmap id is 267
04-09 00:05:09.179  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:32 height:64 bitmap id is 268
04-09 00:05:09.204  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:32 height:8 bitmap id is 269
04-09 00:05:09.209  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:32 height:8 bitmap id is 270
04-09 00:05:09.214  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:16 height:32 bitmap id is 271
04-09 00:05:09.229  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:64 height:128 bitmap id is 272
04-09 00:05:09.254  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:16 height:1 bitmap id is 273
04-09 00:05:09.259  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:16 height:1 bitmap id is 274
04-09 00:05:09.264  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:16 height:32 bitmap id is 275
04-09 00:05:10.729  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary E/libGLESv2﹕ HWUI Protection: wrong calling from app context F:ES3-glDeleteTextures
04-09 00:05:11.149  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:128 height:128 bitmap id is 276
04-09 00:05:11.534  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
04-09 00:05:11.604  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/Ads﹕ Ad finished loading.
04-09 00:05:12.514  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 277
04-09 00:05:12.589  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10139K, 11% free 93881K/105292K, paused 61ms, total 62ms
04-09 00:05:12.599  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 96.918MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:12.644  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 11% free 97975K/109392K, paused 45ms, total 45ms
04-09 00:05:13.264  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:20 height:20 bitmap id is 278
04-09 00:05:13.924  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 279
04-09 00:05:13.984  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4937K, 12% free 93681K/105292K, paused 47ms, total 47ms
04-09 00:05:13.994  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 96.722MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:14.034  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 11% free 97765K/109392K, paused 40ms, total 40ms
04-09 00:05:14.629  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 280
04-09 00:05:14.684  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4300K, 12% free 93706K/105292K, paused 47ms, total 48ms
04-09 00:05:14.694  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 96.748MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:14.739  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 11% free 97800K/109392K, paused 44ms, total 44ms
04-09 00:05:15.249  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 281
04-09 00:05:15.299  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4306K, 11% free 93891K/105292K, paused 43ms, total 43ms
04-09 00:05:15.309  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 96.927MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:15.344  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 187K, 11% free 97799K/109392K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
04-09 00:05:15.899  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 282
04-09 00:05:15.959  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4350K, 11% free 93787K/105292K, paused 43ms, total 44ms
04-09 00:05:15.969  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 96.827MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:16.009  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 97883K/109392K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
04-09 00:05:16.919  30238-31025/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/Volley﹕ [3997] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.88471,151.218237&radius=100&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAs_8InaZfPDzmaD1d9N4ZwXs5dgOB2_gs 0x22cd051c NORMAL 1> [lifetime=10400], [size=182], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
04-09 00:05:17.009  30238-31020/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/Volley﹕ [3992] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.88471,151.218237&radius=100&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAs_8InaZfPDzmaD1d9N4ZwXs5dgOB2_gs 0x22cd051c NORMAL 1> [lifetime=10455], [size=182], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
04-09 00:05:17.094  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 283
04-09 00:05:17.154  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4527K, 11% free 94014K/105292K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
04-09 00:05:17.164  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 97.048MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:17.209  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 98110K/109392K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
04-09 00:05:17.579  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/System.out﹕ {"results":[],"html_attributions":[],"status":"REQUEST_DENIED","error_message":"This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key."}
04-09 00:05:17.614  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/Volley﹕ [1] Request.finish: 11971 ms: [ ] https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.88471,151.218237&radius=100&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAs_8InaZfPDzmaD1d9N4ZwXs5dgOB2_gs 0x22cd051c NORMAL 1
04-09 00:05:17.639  30238-30238/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/Volley﹕ [1] Request.finish: 12042 ms: [ ] https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.88471,151.218237&radius=100&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAs_8InaZfPDzmaD1d9N4ZwXs5dgOB2_gs 0x22cd051c NORMAL 1
04-09 00:05:18.064  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 284
04-09 00:05:18.124  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4392K, 11% free 94017K/105292K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
04-09 00:05:18.134  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 97.051MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:18.174  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 11% free 98111K/109392K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
04-09 00:05:19.004  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 285
04-09 00:05:19.059  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4275K, 11% free 94049K/105292K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
04-09 00:05:19.069  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 97.083MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:19.109  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 11% free 98144K/109392K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
04-09 00:05:19.659  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 286
04-09 00:05:19.709  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4549K, 11% free 94181K/105292K, paused 40ms, total 41ms
04-09 00:05:19.714  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 97.211MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:19.754  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 98277K/109392K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
04-09 00:05:20.174  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 287
04-09 00:05:20.229  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4263K, 11% free 94229K/105292K, paused 45ms, total 46ms
04-09 00:05:20.239  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 97.258MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:20.279  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 11% free 98323K/109392K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
04-09 00:05:20.789  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 288
04-09 00:05:20.854  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4370K, 11% free 94292K/105292K, paused 46ms, total 50ms
04-09 00:05:20.864  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 97.319MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:20.909  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 11% free 98387K/109392K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
04-09 00:05:21.384  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 289
04-09 00:05:21.434  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4375K, 11% free 94342K/105292K, paused 44ms, total 44ms
04-09 00:05:21.444  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 97.369MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:21.484  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 98438K/109392K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
04-09 00:05:21.844  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 290
04-09 00:05:21.889  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4432K, 11% free 94222K/105292K, paused 44ms, total 44ms
04-09 00:05:21.899  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 97.250MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:21.944  30238-30996/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 11% free 98317K/109392K, paused 41ms, total 42ms
04-09 00:05:22.259  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 291
04-09 00:05:22.304  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4419K, 11% free 94161K/105292K, paused 43ms, total 43ms
04-09 00:05:22.314  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 97.192MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:22.349  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 98256K/109392K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
04-09 00:05:22.629  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 292
04-09 00:05:22.679  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4192K, 11% free 94311K/105292K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
04-09 00:05:22.689  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 97.338MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:22.734  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 121K, 11% free 98286K/109392K, paused 44ms, total 44ms
04-09 00:05:23.089  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 293
04-09 00:05:23.134  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4245K, 11% free 94343K/105292K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
04-09 00:05:23.144  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 97.369MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:23.184  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 11% free 98437K/109392K, paused 40ms, total 40ms
04-09 00:05:23.334  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 294
04-09 00:05:23.374  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4159K, 11% free 94298K/105292K, paused 38ms, total 38ms
04-09 00:05:23.384  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 97.326MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:23.424  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 98394K/109392K, paused 38ms, total 38ms
04-09 00:05:23.724  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:768 height:768 bitmap id is 295
04-09 00:05:23.769  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4167K, 11% free 94357K/105292K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
04-09 00:05:23.779  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 97.382MB for 4194320-byte allocation
04-09 00:05:23.819  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 98452K/109392K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
04-09 00:05:26.449  30238-31011/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:64 height:64 bitmap id is 296
```

Comment: did  you debug you code ? what it is returning ?

Comment: @murtazaHussain i did and it return nothing. i just add the logcat

Comment: I found the problem may is that you did not place your `api key` in the URL 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.88471,151.218237&radius=100&sensor=true&key=Key' on `key=Key`, it will return nothing but a `JsonObject` shows `The provided API key is invalid.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was missing the Api key in the url as stated in the document